# pass data from controller to extjs table

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have variables in a controller and I want to display the data from those variables in a extjs xtemplate table.

I had the following line in my controller but nothing passed through:

```
this.getBookOrdersTable().data = {name:BookName, date:OrderDate};
```

BookOrdersTable is a name given to a reference to my table. BookName and OrderDate are the variables with the data that I need.

The code for my table is

```
    this.data = {
        Books: [

        ]
    };

this.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<h1 style="font-size: 2em; padding-bottom: 10px;">Book Orders</h1>',
    '<tpl for="Books">',
    '<table>',
    '<tr>',
    '<th>Book Name: </th>',
    '<td>{name}</td>',
    '</tr>',
    '<tr>',
    '<th>Order Date: </th>',
    '<td>{date}</td>',
    '</tr>',
    '</table>',
    '</tpl>');

this.callParent();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since {name} and {date} are expected to exist within the "Books" object, I don't think you're providing the correct data to XTemplate. What happens if you change <tpl for="Books">... to <tpl for=".">? Or what if you change it to this.getBookOrdersTable().data = {Books=[{name:BookName, date:OrderDate}]}?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I needed to use the update property in the controller call to update the xtemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object is already instantiated, setting the data property won't do anything.  You need to call update.

```
this.getBookOrdersTable().update({
   Books: [
      {name:BookName, date:OrderDate}
   ]
});
```